# SharePoint 2013: Reader cannot access draft pages

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, publishing

A person having reader access cannot access a page which has a minor version(a page in draft). It gives an error:

```
"Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
```

This page is however accessible to SCA.

PS: The current version of page is 2.3(Thus has a published version) and this page is visible to reader in the document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved. The page had reference to another page which had no major issue published. The **DRAFT CHECK** button in the ribbon under pages helped me to figure this out.

[image]